# Config OCSP Admin GUI with ejbca 6.3.1.1 and JBossWildFly 9

Tags: ejbca

I have build OCSP with Admin GUI use source:
- ejbca 6.3.1.1
- JBoss WildFly 9.
- JDK 7.
- ant 1.9
I do the following:

- config.
- ant deploy.
- Config SSL for JBoss with jboss CLI.
  I link to page: https://:8443/ejbca/adminweb error:
  "authorization denied cause : you are not authorized to view this page"
  I have config web.reqcertindb=false in conf/web.properties.
  When I'm having problems with "import certifcate Managment CA (the certificate of the CA that issues administrator certificates) to DB". error:

*Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.command.CliCommandPlugin: Provider org.ejbca.ui.cli.keybind.InternalKeyBindingModifyCommand could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.library.CommandLibrary.(CommandLibrary.java:53)
        at org.ejbca.ui.cli.infrastructure.library.CommandLibrary.(CommandLibrary.java:38)
        at org.ejbca.ui.cli.EjbcaEjbCli.main(EjbcaEjbCli.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:ejbca, moduleName:cesecore-ejb, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@1d9d4b
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:798)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:116)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
        at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.getAvailableTypesAndProperties(Unknown Source)
        at org.ejbca.ui.cli.keybind.InternalKeyBindingModifyCommand.(InternalKeyBindingModifyCommand.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)*

What is my problem?

How I can import certifcate Managment CA??

Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

"No EJB receiver available" means that either EJBCA was not properly deployed, of your JBoss did not start up correctly. 
Check the troubleshooting section of the Amdin Guide to look at the JBoss log to see what is going on.
https://www.ejbca.org/docs/adminguide.html#Troubleshooting